# How to get this footer on my page to align properly with right and left elements?

Tags: html, css

I have this footer at the bottom of my page

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y43rG.png)

Here’s the CSS:

```
.footer {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 10;
    top: 625px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.images {
}
```

So I want that block of text to only exist on the left side of the page, and then a row of images to exist only on the right side. What would be the cleanest way to do this? Might I need bootstrap grid to allow it to properly work? I've tried just doing a margin-left shift but for some reason it adds padding to the bottom of the images, so it increases the height of the page.

Comment: Where is the HTML of your footer ? What do you mean left and right elements ? Could you please clarify this !

Answer (score 1):

Create a parent div containing 2 child divs for the footer-text and footer-images then use flexbox for their alignment and spacing.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand your question -
You could try putting the text that corresponds with certain images in individual `divs` for example if you wanted to put "Hi There!" With an image of some one waving, try this:

```
<div>
   <h1>Hi There!</h1>
   <img src="wavingHand.jpeg">
</div>
```

Then just repeat that for every single pair up, and add this styling:

```
h1 {
  display: inline;
}

img {
  display: inline;
}
```

You can even add some `floats`, or `position: relative` if that isn't the exact effect your looking for

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use somethng like this:

```
.image {
float: right;
position: relative;
margin: 10px 15px 15px 10px;
 }

.text {
   float: left;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="footer">
  <div class="footer-text">Footer Text</div>
  <img src="image.png"> 
</div>

.footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Since there are only 2 children to the the footer element - text and image, you can use justify-content: space-between to evenly distribute the space between the two thereby placing them to left and right ends.